# Can Nexus/Artifactory store copies from a public repository?

Tags: maven, build, repository, nexus, artifactory

The requirements are as follows. We need copies from binaries we need in our projects on our repository server. We can't just proxy the public repository because we had several cases in the past where the binaries on the public repository were changed without changing the release number and we want to avoid problems imposed by that, thus we want to manually specify when to download it from the public repository and when to update. No changes are ever to be made to the binary stored on our repository server without manual interaction.

Is there a way achieve this? I.e. to say "I want artefacts X, Y, Z" copied to my repository server(preferably including their dependencies). Is this possible with either Nexus or Artifactory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. In Nexus define your own local repository, manually download the versions you want and add them to your repository.  You may have to set up "manual routing" for dependency resolution to ensure that Nexus consults the repos in the correct order.

Then make sure your pom files refer to the specific versions you have downloaded.

Comment: So you would download the pom files from the public repository, download the binary from somewhere (product homepage or also the public repository), and then upload it over the web ui or with ant or something?

Comment: Correct. Try it and ask a specific question if you can't get it to work.

Comment: No, this works. It's just a tedious task and I was hoping there was built-in functionality that allows to copy selected artefacts from a public repository. If the auto update for proxy repositories on Nexus could be disabled, this would solve the problem as well. If not, your answer is probably the only solution to my question.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that will make this a little easier is that you can place the downloaded artifacts directly into the local storage directory of a Nexus repository (you don't need to upload them into Nexus).

See here for details:  https://support.sonatype.com/entries/38605563